# How to keep a class consistent between two layout files

Tags: c#, bluetooth, xamarin, xamarin.android

So my problem at the moment is that I have 3 files, two layout files and a custom bluetooth class shared between the two, everything works properly as I would expect on the main layout page when referencing the bluetooth class, my problem is I have a connect function that i run at the users request, then i redirect to my second view. The function looks like so:

```
public void ConnectToDevice()
    {
        BluetoothSocket = SelectedBluetoothDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        BluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery();
        BluetoothSocket.Connect();
    }
```

`SelectedBluetoothDevice` here is set by the user on the main layout before redirecting to the second. Everything seems to work great when i run it, however when I open the new view for the user to do more advanced task (send, recieve serial data) the class is reset. `BluetoothSocket` becomes null, everything needs recalculated, etc. Is there a way to keep this data intact when I open my new view, the only option I can think of is to pass the variables to the new view as parameters then re-set them back up in the bluetooth class, but I was hoping for a more simplistic way without having to do any more hacking than I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i presume, your BluetoothWorker stored as field of first view. If i am right, the problem is in garbage collector, when first view closed and even destroyed, this field may be collected. i think you can use [singleton pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to solve your problem. Here is helper class for simple threafsafe generic singleton.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows to working with class as singleton.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the sole instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The instance.</value>
    static T Instance
    {
        get { return InternalContainer.Instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal instance that guaranties sole instantination.
    /// </summary>
    private class InternalContainer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The sole instance.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly T Instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the <see cref="Singleton&lt;T&gt;.InternalContainer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        static InternalContainer()
        {
            Instance = new T();
        }
    } 
}
```

Just create your own `BluetoothWorkerSingleton : Singleton<BluetoothWorker>` and use it `Instance` property.